# Policy base authorization asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to authorize users in asp.net core 3.1 for example users that have *admin* role and *CanDoSomething* claim.
I Remove AddDefaultIdentity and add pages that i need with scaffolding

ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory :

```
public class ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    { }

    public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

        if (user.CanDoSomething) //it's true
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity)
                .AddClaim(new Claim("CanDoSomething", "true"));
        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("superadmin", policy =>
                policy
                    .RequireRole("admin")
                    .RequireClaim("CanDoSomething", "true"));
        });

        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
    }
```

Configure:

```
public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IWebHostEnvironment env,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        ApplicationDbInitializer.Seed(userManager, roleManager);//Role created and users add to role successfully
    }
```

ApplicationDbInitializer:

```
public static class ApplicationDbInitializer
{
    public static void Seed(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        var roleName = "admin";
        var pw = "@Vv123456";

        roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
        {
            Name = roleName,
            NormalizedName = roleName.ToUpper()
        }).Wait();            

        if (userManager.FindByEmailAsync("b@b.com").Result == null)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "b@b.com",
                Email = "b@b.com",
                CanDoSomething = true
            };

            if (userManager.CreateAsync(user, pw).Result.Succeeded)
                userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
 [Authorize(Policy = "superadmin")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

When i login it redirect me to access denied page
I am doing it right? if yes What should i do now?

Comment: If you login with role admin and Candosomthing claim,you could access the Index successfully.But it redirect to access denied page,it means you do not have the correct role or claim.So,did you use the correct role or not?How did you add role to your user?Could you share more code?

Comment: @Rena Ty for your attention, i edit my post and add ApplicationDbInitializer, i wrote it that role created and user added to role successfully, when i check the db it is ok, and i make `CanDoSomeThing = true` for that user

Answer (score 0):

I make some change and it **worked** but i dont know why

Remove *ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory* and add claim in Seed with AddClaimAsync

In the first way when i check the db and table *AspNetUserClaims* there is no any CanDoSomething claim but i write this and problem solved:

```
userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(CanDoSomething, "true")).Wait();
```

**Why ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory not worked ??**